# gridfilter load store by a custom method

Tags: extjs

if in an extjs grid filter, I set the autorelaod to false and I want to reload the store when the user clicks outside the filter, how do I go about it? I am looking at:
filter.onblur(

check to see if filter value has changed
if yes, 
fire :'updateFilter'
)

Is this correct?
The second question is: If I wish to load the store via a custom loader method...I cannot afford to call 'updatefilter'. But I am at a loss to figure out what are the events I need to fire in sequence so that my custom method will be called.(instead of the default store.load)

Thank you

Comment: post some of your code and we can help you out, your question doesn't really make much sense without seeing your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the event is 'update'.
Explained in docs 'Ext.data.Store-event-update'